# Find out a Dataset's Datasource Name in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I need to find out the NAME of a DATASOURCE used in a dataset in my report. Is there a way / expression to find out and display this on the report?

Like `myDataset.DataSource.Name` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=DataSources("DataSource1").DataSourceReference
```

Will display something like "/DataSources/MyDatabase". It doesn't work in preview mode though

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd255295.aspx

Comment: Should do. Have you deployed the report to the server? Checked your spelling? Can you post your expression?

Comment: Your suggestion does not include asking a DATASET for the datasource name.